# ORA-25156: Old case outer join (+) cannot be used with ANSI joins

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm very very new in programming.
I have no formal education in this field, so I took some online courses and here I am in real life coding.
I read already a post about the problem "ORA-25156: Old case outer join (+) cannot be used with ANSI joins" here in the Forum.
But the thing is, I cannot identify in the code below where is the (+).
What could I do in order to solve this problem?
Thanks a lot in advance!

PS: This code is from a outsourced company which works for us. But they never have time to solve this issue. So, I put my hope on you guys. :-)

I tryied to identify where should be the "non ANSI" code. This without success.

Here is the code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
        TO_CHAR ( '1' ) ,
        PERSON.NAME || ', ' || PERSON.VORNAME,
        PERSON.PERSONALNUMMER ,
        BEHOERDE.KENNNUMMER ,
        ARBEITS_DIENSTVERHAELTNIS.STATUSGRUPPE ,
        XV00004944.LOHNART ,
        TO_DATE ( to_date('2023-08-02' , 'YYYY-MM-DD') , 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) ,
        (ADD_MONTHS ( TO_DATE ( to_date('2023-08-02' , 'YYYY-MM-DD') , 'YYYY-MM-DD' )  , 1 ) ),
        ARBEITS_DIENSTVERHAELTNIS.ADV_ENDE ,
        SACHBEARBEITER.SACHBEARBEITER_SYSTEM_ID ,
        ABRECHNUNGSERGEBNIS.GUELTIG_BIS ,
        SACHBEARBEITER.SACHBEARBEITER_NAME ,
        XV00004944.LOHNART_BEZEICHNUNG  
FROM 
        DWH031.ARBEITS_DIENSTVERHAELTNIS ARBEITS_DIENSTVERHAELTNIS
        JOIN DWH031.ABRECHNUNGSERGEBNIS ABRECHNUNGSERGEBNIS ON  ARBEITS_DIENSTVERHAELTNIS.PERSON_SYSTEM_ID = ABRECHNUNGSERGEBNIS.PERSON_SYSTEM_ID  
        
         JOIN DWH031.ABRECHNUNGSMERKMALE ABRECHNUNGSM ON  ARBEITS_DIENSTVERHAELTNIS.PERSON_SYSTEM_ID = ABRECHNUNGSM.PERSON_SYSTEM_ID  
        
         JOIN DWH031.BEHOERDE BEHOERDE ON  ARBEITS_DIENSTVERHAELTNIS.BEHOERDE_SYSTEM_ID = BEHOERDE.BEHOERDE_SYSTEM_ID   AND  BEHOERDE.GUELTIG_VON <= ? AND BEHOERDE.GUELTIG_BIS >= ? 
        
         JOIN DWH031.FAMILIE FAMILIE ON  ARBEITS_DIENSTVERHAELTNIS.PERSON_SYSTEM_ID = FAMILIE.PERSON_SYSTEM_ID   AND  FAMILIE.GUELTIG_VON <= ? AND FAMILIE.GUELTIG_BIS >= ? 
        
         JOIN DWH031.PERSON PERSON ON  ARBEITS_DIENSTVERHAELTNIS.PERSON_SYSTEM_ID = PERSON.PERSON_SYSTEM_ID   AND  PERSON.GUELTIG_VON <= ? AND PERSON.GUELTIG_BIS >= ? 
        
         LEFT JOIN DWH031.SACHBEARBEITER SACHBEARBEITER ON  PERSON.SACHBEARBEITER_ID_FAMILIENK_A = SACHBEARBEITER.SACHBEARBEITER_SYSTEM_ID   AND  SACHBEARBEITER.GUELTIG_VON <= ? AND SACHBEARBEITER.GUELTIG_BIS >= ? 
         LEFT JOIN XV00004944KRUEGECA50EF08819511 XV00004944 ON  ARBEITS_DIENSTVERHAELTNIS.ADV_SYSTEM_ID = XV00004944.ADVSYSTEMID  
          AND  ( (( XV00004944.LOHNART = ?)) ) 
WHERE 
        ARBEITS_DIENSTVERHAELTNIS.GUELTIG_VON <= ? AND ARBEITS_DIENSTVERHAELTNIS.GUELTIG_BIS >= ?
         AND  ( (( ( ARBEITS_DIENSTVERHAELTNIS.STATUSGRUPPE NOT IN ('R','V')
         AND  ARBEITS_DIENSTVERHAELTNIS.BEHOERDE_SYSTEM_ID NOT IN ('9801','9805','9806','9807','9808','9809','9810','9880'))
         AND  ( ( ARBEITS_DIENSTVERHAELTNIS.STATUSGRUPPE IN ('G','L')
         AND  ARBEITS_DIENSTVERHAELTNIS.ADV_ENDE > TO_DATE ( to_date('2023-08-02' , 'YYYY-MM-DD') , 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) 
         AND  ABRECHNUNGSERGEBNIS.GUELTIG_VON <= TO_DATE ( to_date('2023-08-02' , 'YYYY-MM-DD') , 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) 
         AND  ABRECHNUNGSERGEBNIS.GUELTIG_BIS >= TO_DATE ( to_date('2023-08-02' , 'YYYY-MM-DD') , 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) )
         OR  ( ARBEITS_DIENSTVERHAELTNIS.STATUSGRUPPE = ?
         AND  ARBEITS_DIENSTVERHAELTNIS.ADV_ENDE > (ADD_MONTHS ( TO_DATE ( to_date('2023-08-02' , 'YYYY-MM-DD') , 'YYYY-MM-DD' )  , 1 ) )
         AND  ABRECHNUNGSERGEBNIS.GUELTIG_VON <= (ADD_MONTHS ( TO_DATE ( to_date('2023-08-02' , 'YYYY-MM-DD') , 'YYYY-MM-DD' )  , 1 ) )
         AND  ABRECHNUNGSERGEBNIS.GUELTIG_BIS >= (ADD_MONTHS ( TO_DATE ( to_date('2023-08-02' , 'YYYY-MM-DD') , 'YYYY-MM-DD' )  , 1 ) )))
         AND  ( FAMILIE.KIND_BESITZST_AUSZAHLEN LIKE 'Gem%' ESCAPE '\'
         OR  FAMILIE.KG_FAMILIENZUSCHLAG_AUSZAHLEN = ?))) ) 
ORDER BY 
        2 ASC
```

Comment: The syntax is ANSI SQL compliant. Are there any views involved?

Comment: Most likely one or more of those tables are actually views and use the native Oracle syntax, and Oracle is trying to merge the views and your parent query together into a single block. Try hinting any views with the `no_merge` hint. E.g. if `BEHOERDE` and `FAMILIE` are views, at the very top of your query you should have `SELECT /*+ NO_MERGE(behoerde) NO_MERGE(familie) */ DISTINCT  ...` . That will prevent view merging which should keep the blocks separate and you shouldn't get the error.

Comment: **NEVER** use `TO_DATE` on something that is already a date. So `TO_DATE ( to_date('2023-08-02' , 'YYYY-MM-DD') , 'YYYY-MM-DD' )` is at best pointless and, at worst, harmful as it can give unexpected results. Just use `to_date('2023-08-02' , 'YYYY-MM-DD')` or, even simpler, `DATE '2023-08-02'`.

Comment: Check the view definitions.

Comment: Answering the question jarlh - What is generated there is showed in form of an Excel table. If is this you wanted to know.

Comment: Thank you very very much for your answer guys. I'm going to apply the suggestions and come back here to post what happened. :-)

Comment: Hello Paul W - "BEHOERDE" and "FAMILIE" are tables. But I'm going to apply your suggestion and see what happens. As I'm new in the company it will take a while because I'm dependning on the senior guys.